# two singletons referencing each other is crashing unity

Tags: c#, design-patterns, static, unity-game-engine

I have the following two singletons:

```
public sealed class MyClass : ISomeInterface<anotherClass>
{ 
  private static MyClass instance = null;
  private ISomeInterface <anotherClass> parentState = Other.Instance; // error
  private ISomeInterface <anotherClass> childState = null; 
  private MyClass(){}

public static MyClass Instance
{
    get
    {
         if(instance == null)
         {
            instance = new MyClass();
         }
         return instance;
     }
 }
}

public sealed class Other : ISomeInterface<anotherClass>
{ 
  private static Other instance = null;
  private ISomeInterface <anotherClass> parentState = null;
  private ISomeInterface <anotherClass> childState = MyClass.Instance; 
  private Other(){}

public static Other Instance
{
    get
    {
         if(instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Other();
         }
         return instance;
     }
 }
}
```

Unfortuntately I don't get any error but as soon as I am accessing the parentState of Myclass Unity3d crashes. I also cannot have a break point near the initialization.

When I am initializing the field in the Instance Property it works. It also works when I set the fields static like:

```
private static ISomeInterface<anotherClass> parentState = Other.Instance;
```

Can anyone explain me why my first approach does not work?

Comment: My guess would be that there they are calling each others "Instance" field recursively by initializing childState / parentState repeatedly when the instance is first created. E.g. calling Other.Instance really is not atomic, it's a function like Other.GetInstance(). It's again creating an object of Other. This again calls MyClass.GetInstance(), which again creates ANOTHER Other.instance (since "instance" has no value yet..) This continues forever.

Comment: "two singletons referencing each other" reeks of a major design flaw

Comment: You have a infinite recursion by creating instances and hence `StackOverflowException`. Design is terribly flawed.

Comment: so I don't get it why it works when the fields are static? I know that this design is flawed I just want to know why it does not work

Comment: Just catch the StackOverflowException in the debugger and you will see why it happens.  Pick "Debug" -> "Exceptions" -> "Find.." -> type in "StackOverflow" and check "Thrown".  Also, see here for how to create a global singleton: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: changing the code to the implementation of csharpindepth does not prevent the error. I just don't understand why changing the field to static makes it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

You are creating infinite recursion by creating a new instance each time, which eventually will lead to a StackOverflowException. This is because you are insisting on each Singleton having a reference to the other.

---

#### Why static works

Static won't give you the problem because `"execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class."` -- [Static field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx).

---

#### Another way you can solve the problem

If you make both Singletons use eager instantiation instead of lazy you won't have this problem. Eager instantiation looks like this:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton getInstance { get { return instance; } }
}
```

This will work because it won't depend on who calls the Singleton to create the instance.

Comment: Thanks I get it now. So having eager instantiation in my case is the better way then having the static fields since it is more clear and because the fields are static they are immediately executed anyway. Correct?

Comment: as a sidenote, I would avoid having static properties initialized inline --that's what static cTors are for. 
In case you're new-ing a complex object and its initialization fails you won't get a proper stack trace in the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop by constructor member creation referencing eachothers constructors:

In MyClass you have:

```
private ISomeInterface <anotherClass> parentState = Other.Instance;
```

In Other Class you have:

```
private ISomeInterface <anotherClass> childState = MyClass.Instance;
```

ie. MyClass creation causes Other creation, causes MyClass creation...etc.

The reason it works when these members are **static** is that static members are initialized before the static member is accessed for the first time and before the static constructor, if there is one, is called.